# Blender Texture Painting Problem

Tags: textures, blender

I'm trying to texture paint a character in blender, however I'm running into a problem. I'm able to use the fill tool to color in the mesh, but the draw doesn't do anything.

For example, when I use the fill tool and choose a color like blue, then click the character, it turns blue. But when I select the draw tool and try to color the character, nothing happens. [image]

[image]

Here's a picture of my UV's. I think I got everything for the texture painting to work. Does anybody know why it doesn't?!?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the answer; I went over to the textures properties tab, and then deleted the texture that I had applied to the brush unknowingly. Because I didn't have any texture painting texture, the brush didn't output anything.